Suppose $b$ and $d$ are real numbers, $d\neq{0}$. Consider the poly $P(z)=z^4+bz^2+d$. Prove that $d=\frac{b^2}{4}$.
Suppose $b$ and $d$ are real numbers, $d\neq{0}$. Consider the poly $P(z)=z^4+bz^2+d$ which has a double root at $\alpha$ and -$\alpha$. Now it is also given (and easily proved) that $P'(z)$ is an odd function.
Prove that $d=\frac{b^2}{4}$.

What I Tried:
Consider the discriminant
$$\Delta=b^2-4d$$
So arrive at the required identity, we need to prove that the poly has one distinct real root (ie, it contacts the $x$-axis at one point). But this polynomial is an even function. So if it contacts the $x$-axis as one point say $X$, then it contacts the $x$-axis at point $-X$ also. Which means there are two distinct real roots. So How can I possibly show that $\Delta=0$?
The next Question asks me to find what values of $b$ does $P(z)$ have real roots?
I thought about letting $d=0$. But that wasn't allowed.
Then I thought about how the real roots -$\alpha$ and $\alpha$ necessarily have to have imaginary parts $x+iy$, $y=0$. So I thought maybe I should expand $P(z=x+iy)=0+0i$, then equate imaginary part and real parts, let $y=0$ (which leaves behind two equations in terms of $x$). Then solve each one and the solution will be the $x$ values that satisfy both equations. Then...but maybe I am going down a rabbit hole. I think I am supposed to use the previous $\Delta$ identity thing.

Your discriminant $\Delta$ actually only works for quadratic equation. So if you decide to use such discriminant, then you are actually considering the "quadratic equation" in variable $z^2$, that is the equation
$$(z^2)^2+b(z^2)+d$$
Note this equation has a repeated root in $\alpha^2$ as $\alpha$ is a repeated root to the degree $4$ polynomial (now $\alpha$ and $-\alpha$ are the same root as we consider the square of the variable), it follows that the discriminant is $0$, so $b^2=4d$.
On the other hand, you can also use Vieta's so that $$b=\alpha(\alpha)+2\alpha(-\alpha)+2\alpha(-\alpha)+(-\alpha)(-\alpha)=-2\alpha^2$$
$$d=\alpha^2(-\alpha)^2=\alpha^4$$
We again arrive $b^2=4d$.
To make the equation has real root, you need $b\le 0$ as $\alpha^2$ has to be nonnegative. This is also a sufficient condition.

The roots for the equation $P(z)=z^4+bz^2+d$ is
$$z^{2} = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^{2} - 4d}}{2}$$,
Given that it has a double root $\alpha$ and $-\alpha$, which demands $b^{2} = 4d$ so that $z = -\sqrt{-b/2},\sqrt{-b/2}$ then $P(z)$ has real roots if $b \leq 0$.

Using binomial formulas and that a polynomial given by its full root set and leading coefficient is unique, one finds that
$$
P(z)=(z^2-\alpha^2)^2=z^4-2\alpha^2z^2+\alpha^4.
$$
The claim follows.
